# Why is it taking so long to download a zip file through AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blob

On my webpage, there is a feature to let user downloading a zip file. The way it works as after user clicked the download button, a GET request would be sent to the api, and then server sends back the file data as arraybuffer. Then the UI converts the data into a blob object and save it as a zip file. Here is the sample code for that:

```
function download(){

    var req = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: "api/download",
      contentType: "application/zip",
      responseType: "arraybuffer",
      headers: {"Accept": "application/zip"}
    };

    $http(req).then(function (res) {
        if(res.status === 200){
           var file = new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/zip" });
           var link = document.createElement('a');
           link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
           link.download = "MyFile.zip";
           document.body.appendChild(link);
           link.click();
           document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    }, function (err) {});

}
```

The code works great except for one issue: the overall process seems taking too long to complete. Even for a zip file that only 100kb, it still gonna cost at least 2 minutes to download. When I check the dev tool, I noticed the data transfer process finished in almost 3-5 seconds, and then the program was like just halting there for another 2 minutes before proceeding to the next step. (meanwhile the dev tool keep showing the request is still going on). What make it seems more peculiar is that I have some test files that are in different sizes, say from 100KB to 150MB, and the downloading time are roughly the same (in less than 5 seconds different).

Can someone elaborate on what could be the cause, and how can I improve this? Or if there is a better way to achieve the goal through a different workflow/model?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Couple questions.  Have you tried commenting out the code line by line to identify the time heavy command?  Also have you tried doing this without creating the Blob?  I've done stuff like this with endpoints that return pdfs and didn't have to create a blob, iirc.

Comment: @Taplar I suspect this may have something to do with the Blob. But I don't know how to get zip file from arraybuffer without using Blob. I've done pdf and csv file with Bolb as well but none of them has such issue before, even some pdf files are over 50mb the downloading time seems consistent. I guess what confused me most is the fact it costs the same amount of time to convert a 100kb file vs a 100mb file?

Comment: I would reflect on Yserbius's answer below.  I would assume a better approach would be for the server to return the file in the format it is expected in already, rather than transforming it in javascript, so all you have to do is just make the object url and have them download it.

Comment: You can set the responseType to 'blob' so you don't have to create a Blob and use up extra memory

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you're temporarily storing the ZIP file in the clients browser memory via the Blob where it's getting stored *twice* (once as the resultant data, once as a Blob). This looks like something that would work a lot better if you just have the server generate the zip as a temporary file and send the client a link to that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately I don't have control over the server side code at the moment so I need to figure something out on the UI for the time being. Do you know if there is a way to convert the arraybuffer data to zip file without using Blob?

Comment: Why don't you just create a link to the URL of the file itself?

Comment: Because there is no URL of the file.. Server created the file on the fly but rather than store it somewhere on the server, it just send back the binary data to the UI so the file has to be assembled at client site.